# I am encountering an issue in Databricks where I have uploaded a CSV file to an S3 bucket, but it's being incorrectly recognized as a Delta file

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, azure-databricks

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

## Create a Spark session

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("S3DataAccess").getOrCreate()

## Define the URL to the CSV file

s3_url = "https://testbucket1409.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/Manifest.csv"

## Read the CSV file from the S3 URL

df = spark.read.csv(s3_url, header=True, inferSchema=True)

A transaction log for Delta was found at `https://testbucket1409.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/ManifestData.csv/_delta_log`,
but you are trying to read from `https://testbucket1409.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/ManifestData.csv` using format("csv"). You must use
'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table.

Comment: Looks like ManifestData.csv is a folder, not a file. So Databricks try to read the entire folder. Try to use a URL with filename, or remove the _delta_log folder.

Comment: ManifestData is a file i have uploaded it from my local to s3  @ChenHirsh

Comment: the error say that _delta_log folder exists inside ManifestData.csv. Could there be a folder with the same name as the file? also try to create a folder, put the file in it and test from there.

Comment: you know "infer schema" means "read the entire s3 file in the spark driver before even scheduling tasks to the workers", right? Because that is what it has to do to infer the schema.

Comment: also, the root path of an s3 store is sometimes trouble with spark, hive etc. it's special as it doesn't have a parent and can't be deleted. It's usually best to start one level down

Comment: i agree with you @stevel but here i am using a csv file and trying to read using read.csv, but it is recognizing as delta file

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @[Chen Hirsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21079004/chen-hirsh) that when you try to read a delta table as dataframe using csv format, you will get the above error.

**My Delta table:**

[image]

You can see that it is saying to read it as delta table in the error.

[image]

So, first try to check your path is delta table or not.

```
from delta import DeltaTable
print(DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, "/FileStore/tables/delta_train.csv"))
```

If it results true, you need to read it like below.

```
spark.read.format("delta").load("/FileStore/tables/delta_train.csv", header=True).show()
```

[image]

If it returns false, try to create new folder and read it as csv as suggested in comments.